# Is there an easy way to find $2^p \pmod p$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I'm working on a number theory problem, and was able to simplify an expression down to a quadradic in $2^p \pmod p$? Is there an easy way to compute that, or must I work it out in $O(p)$ complexity?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p=2$, then of course $2^p\equiv 0\pmod p$.If $p\neq 2$, then, [by Fermat little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), we find that $2^p\equiv 2\pmod p$.

Answer (score 4):

It's congruent to 2 mod p by Fermat's little theorem.